# Convert Illustrator drop shadow to CSS

Tags: adobe-illustrator, css, shadows

How would the CSS values of these parameters:

[image]

Look like in CSS? I'm curious if there is way to convert these values also for future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract CSS straight from Illustrator... though I think it may be limited to the CC version.

Select the object and go `Window > CSS Properties`

[image]

Now if you want to save this drop shadow in illustrator, you can drag the object with the shadow into the `Window > Graphic Styles` panel. The contents of this panel are not global in the sense that if you open a new document, that graphic style won't be there. After adding a new graphic style, you need to save the graphic library (fly-out menu in the panel) and load it in future projects.

Comment: For me, this solution displays colors, dimensions, and the border radius, but not the drop shadow. Does anyone know why this could be?

Answer (score 1):

What about using an online shadow generator like this one [html-css-js.com](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/), has exactly the same parameters:

[image]

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

---

Another option: [css3studio.com](http://css3studio.com/page-css3/css-box-shadow.php)

[image]

```
.css-box-shadow{
/*start ------------*/
width: [object Object]px; 
height: [object Object]px; 
background: #F8F8F8; 
border: solid #BDBDBD 1px; 
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)  ; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)  ; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)  ; 
}
```

Comment: This is not directly related but there is a little editor in the Chrome dev tools. Doesn't add vendor prefixes but it can make it easier to adjust shadows: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZdsz.png)